# Powershell v2 files deletion error Cannot convert the "LastWriteTime"

Tags: powershell

**OS : Windows 2008 R2 64bit**

I am trying to delete all txt files older then X days using powershell using below CMD

```
PS C:\temp> POWERSHELL -COMMAND "Get-ChildItem c:\temp -Recurse -Include *.txt | Where LastWriteTime -lt  (Get-Date).AddDays(-10) | Remove-Item -Force"
```

But getting following error

```
Where-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert the "LastWriteTime" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".At line:1 char:54+ Get-ChildItem c:\temp -Recurse -Include *.txt | Where <<<<  LastWriteTime -lt  (Get-Date).AddDays(-10) | Remove-Item -Force    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand
```

PS version:

```
PS C:\temp>  $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1
Howto sort it?
```

Comment: Use `Where-Object{...}` syntax. As aside: why are you still using that old version of PoewerShell? and Why do you run it via CMD and not in PowerShell straight away?

Comment: I am using it in BATCH file to execute multiple functions and email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

???.... and you can use PowerShell directly to execute as much code, .ps1 files, and functions as you choose in a single run. No need for separate code runs and you don't need cmd.exe for that, though you can if you choose to.

Since PowerShell is doing the function run (the work) anyways, and code/these functions are PowerShell code (assuming here), then again, just put that is a single .ps1 file and run it directly

```
# Contents of SomeName.ps1 file

Get-ChildItem -path (c:\temp -Recurse -Include *.txt).FullName | 
ForEach {
    $PSItem| 
    Where LastWriteTime -lt  (Get-Date).AddDays(-10) | 
    Remove-Item -Force
}


powershell '.\SomeName.ps1'
```